# How to port a java Spring application to run in AWS Lambda

Tags: spring, aws-lambda

I would like to port my Java Spring application to run in AWS Lambda. Is it possible? Are there any resources you could point me to? There are some tutorials available for Express, but not for Java Spring applications. Would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda is serverless and have limitation to upload binary and max execution time is 15 min.

You really not need Spring or any other framwork to run lambda as its working on own framwork

Plz share your usecase why need sparing with Lambda

Comment: said rightly , but still you can deploy using micro services on lambda.

Comment: You can directly expose your lambda or dynamodb on API gateway and  using transformation return response as microservice , for writing microservice on lambda not required Spring or any other framwork .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-blueprint.html

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. I would like to port these apps to AWS lambda: https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat and https://github.com/bkimminich/juice-shop....These apps serve very specific purpose. There is a specific reason I would like port them to aws lambda. I know I can do research to figure out feasibility, but I am looking for shortcuts :-). Would appreciate pointers.

Comment: You need to understand Aws lambda ,it works on trigger so you can expose ur aws lambda, rest end point on api gateay and use this api in ur code .so on trigger rest you can invoke lambda .